# Removing samples based on unique and nan values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a data-frame like this:

```
   dtf:
       id   f1    f2   f3    f4     f5
       t1   34    12    5    nan    6
       t1   nan    4    2    9      7
       t1   34    nan   5    nan    6
       t2   nan   nan  nan   nan   nan    
       t2   nan   nan  nan   nan   nan    
       t2   nan   nan  nan   nan   nan
       t3   23     7    8     1     32    
       t3   12     3   nan    45    56    
       t3   nan   nan  nan   nan    nan
```

I want to remove those rows (which have unique id) and all the features' values are 'nan' (like t2). Thus my desired data-frame should be like this:

```
  dtf_new:
       id   f1    f2   f3    f4     f5
       t1   34    12    5    nan    6
       t1   nan    4    2    9      7
       t1   34    nan   5    nan    6           
       t3   23     7    8     1     32    
       t3   12     3   nan    45    56    
       t3   nan   nan  nan   nan    nan
```

I have tried to convert it a dictionary using the below code, and then try to find nan values. But I still could not find the right solution.

```
 dict=dict(enumerate(dtf.id.unique()))
```

Comment: please make an attempt before asking for help. are you using a particular library?

Comment: have you tried df.dropna()? make sure those 'nan' (if strings) are replaced with numpy.nan.

Comment: why row at index position 2 is removed?

Comment: it was removed by mistake. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do `groupby` and `isna`:

```
>>> dtf
   id    f1    f2   f3    f4    f5
0  t1  34.0  12.0  5.0   NaN   6.0
1  t1   NaN   4.0  2.0   9.0   7.0
2  t1  34.0   NaN  5.0   NaN   6.0
3  t2   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
4  t2   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
5  t2   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
6  t3  23.0   7.0  8.0   1.0  32.0
7  t3  12.0   3.0  NaN  45.0  56.0
8  t3   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
>>> dtf_new = dtf[~dtf['id'].map(dtf.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.drop(columns='id').isna().all(axis=None)))]
>>> dtf_new
   id    f1    f2   f3    f4    f5
0  t1  34.0  12.0  5.0   NaN   6.0
1  t1   NaN   4.0  2.0   9.0   7.0
2  t1  34.0   NaN  5.0   NaN   6.0
6  t3  23.0   7.0  8.0   1.0  32.0
7  t3  12.0   3.0  NaN  45.0  56.0
8  t3   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

@sacse is right, dropna does the job

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Just change default "how" parameter...

These kinds of processing needs are basic, and common to most of pandas users... You can assume there is a feature for it, few mins on the documentation and you will find your answer, and other interesting features :)

Worth some time reading!

Comment: df.dropna() removes the rows which have all the items nan, but I need something that delete if all the rows from a unique id are nan, not one specific row. E.g., t2 has that criteria.